# working on websockets javascript and golang server trying send files and images

Tags: javascript, json, go, websocket, socket.io

json object sending from front-end javascript websockets is like

```
message_type: "1"
to: "umesh"
from: "moin"
body: ""
file: "{"filename":"reportesmtp.pdf" 
       ,"fileextension":"application/pdf" ,"filesize":61813 
       ,"filedata":"37,80,6848,52,48,57,....,10,37,37,69,79,70,10"}
       "
message_id: "9"
message_stage_id: "0"
```

this data is sent by

```
//javascript
websocket.send(data)
```

after some modifiactions and being recieved on a server written in golang at

```
//golang
websocket.JSON.Receive(u.Ws, &msg)
```

the above give err as

```
err:  unexpected end of JSON input
err:  invalid character ',' after top-level value
err:  invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value
```

however works fine till file size is approx 35kb.
on successfull 
not using socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

The client fragments the message when the file is larger than approximately 35kb.  The golang.org/x/net/websocket package [does not handle fragmented messages](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7632).

Fix by using one of the websocket packages recommended in the [golang.org/x/net/websocket documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket):

- [github.com/gorilla/websocket](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket)
- [nhooyr.io/websocket](https://godoc.org/nhooyr.io/websocket)